# Wordpress theme works on linux servers but white screen after move to Xampp

Tags: themes, server, local-installation

I have a client who needed me to set up a test environment locally to test patches for his site before I moved them to production.

I created a new WordPress install on XAMPP (windows machine) and copied the files from the site, the admin area works but the front end only shows a white screen, no errors.

I then installed the theme on a clean Linux server install of WordPress and the theme worked.

What am I missing? Is there a difference that WordPress would know between the 2 servers?

Comment: Whitescreen is just hidden problems - do you have `WP_DEBUG` turned on? do your logs on the xampp server have any errors?

Comment: No errors, I have enabled every log, and disabled all plugins.

Comment: how about using a default twenty-x theme? what versions of PHP are your two servers running? does visiting backend /wp-admin/ instead of just the front end load? do normal .php hello world scripts run on xampp? have you turned off rewrites / rule out htaccess error? do `homeurl` and `siteurl` match for their respective servers?

Comment: The default theme works, all scripts work normally. The url match and the admin area does load.

Comment: well if admin loads and front page white screens, then it's 100% the theme or a plugin. Historically I found it to be a theme/plugin with bad code, either php shorthand tags or php code that doesn't work on older php version (simple things like having a function inside of `empty()` function). The site white-screens because of a fatal error, I'm disbelieved your Apache error logs would show nothing.